# Text encoding for swedish characters goes wrong in YAML

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to use parametrized reports in RStudio. But when I use params with swedish characters with umlauts (like å, ä ö) something goes wrong with the encoding. I'm running Windows 10 on my computor.

Example:

````
title: "test_yaml_encoding"
output: html_document
params:
  swe_chars_param: "åäöÅÄÖ"


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
print(params$swe_chars_param)
```
````

[1] "Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶Ã…Ã„Ã–"

It seems to be a known issue:
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/420
but I have not mangaged to find a solution.

One solution is to fix the encoding with a function. I have tried two different solutions.

First try:

```
ffix_swedish_chars <- function(txt) {
  txt <- gsub("Ã¥", "å", txt)
  txt <- gsub("Ã¤", "ä", txt)
  txt <- gsub("Ã¶", "ö", txt)
  txt <- gsub("Ã…", "Å", txt)
  txt <- gsub("Ã„", "Ä", txt)
  txt <- gsub("Ã–", "Ö", txt)
}

print(ffix_swedish_chars(params$swe_chars_param))
```

Result:

[1] "åäöÃ…Ã„Ã–"

It worked, but only for lower case letters.

Then I tried to use brute force and tried to loop through all possible encodings to UTF-8

```
library(utf8)
library(purrr)
library(readr)


koder <- iconvlist()


ftest_kodning <- function(str, kod) {
  iconv(str, from = kod, to = "UTF-8")
}

ftest_kodning_safe <- possibly(ftest_kodning, NA)

for (i in 1:length(koder)) {
  print(paste(koder[i], ftest_kodning_safe(params$swe_chars_param, koder[i])))
}
```

I couldn't find any combination of encoding that worked.

Now I'm stuck. Does anyone have a solution?

Edit:

I don't know if this is of any help but this is the raw codes for the characters:

> print(charToRaw(params$swe_chars_param))
>    [1] c3 83 c2 a5 c3 83 c2 a4 c3 83 c2 b6 c3 83 e2 80 a6 c3 83 e2 80 9e c3 83 e2 80 93